# Is there a way to use LSTM to predict a time-series with an exogenous variable like there is when using SARIMAX models?

Tags: python, time-series, forecast

I was trying to forecast a time-series with exogenous variables and have been successful in forecasting with SARIMAX models, I was trying to do the same using RNN models (specifically LSTM model) but was unable to find any way to implement an exogenous variable (which I have the complete history of), but this variable affects the time-series and thus needs to be accounted for.
Greatly appreciate your help
Thank you

Comment: care to elaborate a bit more on how you're successfully including exogenous variables in your SARIMAX models and how/where it seems you're finding difficulty including it similarly in your RNN models?

Comment: Hi, @rigsby. I used the exog attribute in the SARIMAX function: model=SARIMAX(train_data,exog=exogenous_train, order=..,seasonal_order=...)  and then to predict I used the forecast which gave me the option of defining an exogenous variable for the prediction explicitly: fc = model.forecast(steps, exog=exogenous_test). However, I cannot seem to figure out how to do the same in the LSTM models.

Answer (score 1):

Check [cond-rnn](https://github.com/philipperemy/cond_rnn). It is a library that implements what you are looking for.

> Useful if you have time series data with other inputs that do not
>   depend on time. For example, weather data from two different cities:
>   Paris and San Francisco. You want to predict the next temperature
>   based on historical data. But at the same time, you expect the weather
>   to change based on the city. You can either:
>
> - Combine the auxiliary features with the time series data (ugly!).
> - Concatenate the auxiliary features with the output of the RNN layer. It's some kind of post-RNN adjustment since the RNN layer won't see this auxiliary info.
> - Or just use this library! Long story short, initialize the RNN states with a learned representation of the condition (e.g. Paris or San Francisco). This way you model elegantly P(x_{t+1}|x_{0:t}, cond).

And it is really easy to use

```
outputs = cond_rnn.ConditionalRNN(units=NUM_CELLS, cell='LSTM')([inputs, cond])
```